# IPv6 2 Compression Rules to shortest form

Tags: compression, ipv6

Original IPv6 Address
0​0​e​b​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:​0​0​0​0​:​d​8​c​1​:​0​9​4​6​:​0​2​7​2​:​0​8​7​9​

edit each IPv6 address until it is in the shortest form possible

My A:
eb::​d​8​c​1​:​9​4​6​:​​2​7​2​:​8​79

This is not correct. What did I do wrong/am missing?

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4

Answer (score 0):

Visually, what you did is fine. However, if I copy and paste what you actually entered in your question, I find an invisible zero-width Unicode space (`\u200b`) between every visible character! (For both your initial and edited IPv6 addresses.) I don't know how you got those in there, but that may be what is causing your issue.